# How to replace to apostrophe ' inside a file using SED

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a file "test.txt" that contain the following

```
+foo+
+bar+
```

What I want to do is to replace them into:

```
'foo'
'bar'
```

But why this code doesn't work?

```
sed  's/\+/\'/' test.txt
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `"` instead. And add `g` flag to replace all.

```
sed  "s/\+/\'/g" test.txt
```

Comment: sed  "s/\$/\'/g" ut.txt - this is adding ' at the end instead replacing the $ character. am i missing something?

Comment: As [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18119525) mentions, `+` is not a metacharacter without the `-r` option, thus `sed "s/+/'/g" test.txt` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for yoyu (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/+/'\''/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

`+` is not a special character without `-r` switch in sed. You can run the **substitute command without any escaping**:

```
echo '+foo+' | sed "s/+/'/g"

# output: 'foo'
```

If you want to save changed file then use:

```
sed -i.bak "s/+/'/g" test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also replace all instances of `+` with `'` in the file by using `tr`:

```
tr '+' "'" < inputfile
```