# How to correctly detect and replace apostrophe (') with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm having a directory with many files having special characters and spaces. I want to perform an operation with all these files so I'm trying to store all filenames in a `list.txt` and then run the command with this list.

The special characters in my list are `& []'`.

So basically I want to use `sed` to replace each occurence with `\` + the character in question.

E.g. : `filename .txt` => `filename\ .txt` etc...

The thing is I have trouble handling apostrophes.

Here is my command as of now :

```
 ls | sed 's/\ /\\ /g' | sed 's/\&/\\&/g' | sed "s/\'/\\'/g" | sed 's/\[/\\[/g' | sed 's/\]/\\]/g'
```

At first I had issues with, I believe, the apostrophes in the string command in conflict with the apostrophes surrounding the string. So I used double quotes instead, but it still doesn't work.

I've tried all these and nothing worked :

`sed "s/\'/\\'/g"` (escaping the apostrophe)

`sed "s/'/\'/g"` (escaping nothing)

`sed "s/'/\\'/g"` (escaping the backslash)

`sed 's/"'"/\"'"/g'` (double quoting single quote)

As a disclaimer, I must say, I'm completely new to `sed`. I just run my first `sed` command today, so maybe I'm doing something wrong I didn't realize.

PS : I've seen those thread, but no answer worked for me :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157076/how-to-remove-the-apostrophe-and-delete-the-space

[How to replace to apostrophe ' inside a file using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119433/how-to-replace-to-apostrophe-inside-a-file-using-sed)

Comment: It depends on how you're going to use the filenames, but you probably don't want to add escapes to them. Instead, use the techniques in [BashFAQ #20](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) to safely handle filenames with weird characters.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the link. I agree it is a lot better in terms of good practices, but here I want to do it in cli and not with a bash script.

I believe for the current use, it is exactly what I need to do since I'm calling a command which will process something on each file given, so it's like I'm calling the command at the cli and need to escape every special character so that it can find the file.

Answer (score 4):

This may do:

```
cat file
avbadf
test&rr
more [ yes
this ]
and'df
```

```
sed -r 's/(\x27|&|\[|\])/\\\1/g' file
avbadf
test\&rr
more \[ yes
this \]
and\'df
```

- `\x27` is equal to singe quote `'`
- `\x22` is equal to double quote `"`

Comment: And I guess \1 is equal to the pattern we found before ?

This actually didn't work. Everything was replaced by `\1`

Comment: Edit : It worked with 5 backslashes ^^ : "s/(\x27|&|\[|\]|\ )/\\\\\1/g"

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, I found the answer to my question. Here is the working input :

`sed "s/'/\\\'/g"`

This will effectively replace any `'` with `\'`.

However I'm having trouble understanding exactly what's happening here.

So if I understand correctly, we are escaping the backslash and the apostrophe in the replacement string. Now, if somebody could answer some those, I would be grateful :

- Why don't we need to escape the first quote (the one in the pattern to find) ?
- Why do we have to escape the backslash whereas for the other characters, there's no need ?
- Why do we need to escape the second quote (the one in the replacement string) ?

Comment: 1. Because apostrophes not special in double quotes and not special in sed. 2. Because backslashes are special to both double quotes and to sed. 3. You don't, but you need to escape your backslashes (twice, once for double quotes and once for sed). Preferably this is `\\\\'` but `\\\'` works too because bash will consider the unrecognized escape `\'` as literal `\'` (unlike sed, where unrecognized `\'` becomes literal `'`)

Comment: another way to write `'` "inside" single quotes is `'"'"'`

Comment: @Jasen Nope. I had already tried `sed 's/"'"/\"'"/g'` or even `sed 's/"'"/\\"'"/g'` as found in the second link I provided. This didn't work. At least it doesn't work for this specific usecase.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for your answers. However for 2. you say we need to escape the backslash twice, once for double quote and once for sed, but again we don't backslash it once for sed for the other characters &[] etc... How so ?

Answer (score 1):

I think all of your sed matches actually need that replacement pattern. This one seems to work for all examples:

```
ls | sed "s/\ /\\\ /g" | sed "s/\&/\\\&/g" | sed "s/\[/\\\[/g" | sed "s/\]/\\\]/g" | sed "s/'/\\\'/g"
```

So it is s/regex/replacement/command and 'regex' and 'replacement' have different sets of special characters.

The only one that's different is `s/'/\\\'/g` and there only because I don't believe there is any special ' character on the regex expression.  There is some obscure \' special character in the replacement expression, for matching buffer ends in multi-line mode, accord to the docs. That might be why it needs an escape in the replacement side, but not in the regex side.

For example, \5 is a special character in the replacement expression, so to replace:

```
filename5.txt -> filename\5.txt
```

You would also need, as with apostrophe:

```
sed "s/5/\\\5/g"
```

It probably has to do with the mysterious inner works of sed parsing, it might read from right to left or something.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
sed 's/[][ &'\'']/\\&/g' file
```

By using the same example by @Jotne, the result will be:

```
gavbadf
gtest\&rr
gmore\ \[\ yes
gthis\ \]
gand\'df
```

**[How it works]**

- The `regex` part in the `sed` `s` command above just defines a character
  class of `& []'`, which should be escaped with a backslash.
- The right square bracket `]` does not need escaping when put
  immediately after the left square bracket `[`.
- The obfuscating part will be the handling of a single quote.
  We cannot put a single quote within single quotes even if we escape it.
  The workaround is as follows: Say we have an assignment `str='aaabbb'`.
  To put a single quote between "aaa" and "bbb", we can say as
  `str='aaa'\''bbb'`.
  It may look puzzling but it just concatenates the three sequences;
  1) to close the single-quoted string as `'aaa'`.
  2) to put a single quote with an escaping backslash as `\'`.
  3) to restart the single-quoted string as `'bbb'`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Year ! Thanks for the comment. Please forgive my boldness to pick your advice in my answer :)